# How to change moodle moove category list on front page to cards?

Tags: php, moodle

I have been working on a moodle site for some time and hit a wall regarding development.

When working on the site I am wanting to get the category's to display as cards like in image 1:

[image: Example image of cards]

However, the category's are just displaying as a list on the page like in image 2:

[image: How category's current display]

Does anyone know I can change the category's to show the cards of the example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to change the behaviour on front page, since your screenshot looks like category combo. The behaviour is rendered in /index.php , find the `case FRONTPAGECATEGORYCOMBO:` line. I strongly recommend not to modify index.php directly, but use [customscripts mechanism](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/customscripts) to do this